# Vb.net 2 Signatures

Tags: vb.net, signature

Im quite finished with my program, there are only 2 more things to do. But now lets focus on my main problem: Ive got a code, that gives the user the possibility to draw inside a picturebox, that will work later as a signature. Everything was working fine until I added a second picturebox with the same code( yes I changed for ex. picturebox1 to pixturebox2). As I start drawing I cant let go and both pictureboxes are getting interracted at the same time.
That my code for both pictureboxes.

```
  Private _Previous As System.Nullable(Of Point) = Nothing
Private Sub pictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    _Previous = e.Location
    pictureBox1_MouseMove(sender, e)
End Sub
Private Sub pictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If _Previous IsNot Nothing Then
        If PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing Then
            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
            Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
                g.Clear(Color.White)
            End Using
            PictureBox1.Image = bmp
        End If
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, _Previous.Value, e.Location)
        End Using
        PictureBox1.Invalidate()
        _Previous = e.Location
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub pictureBox2_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseDown
    _Previous = e.Location
    pictureBox1_MouseMove(sender, e)
End Sub

Private Sub pictureBox2_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseMove
    If _Previous IsNot Nothing Then
        If PictureBox2.Image Is Nothing Then
            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(PictureBox2.Width, PictureBox2.Height)
            Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
                g.Clear(Color.White)
            End Using
            PictureBox2.Image = bmp
        End If
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox2.Image)
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, _Previous.Value, e.Location)
        End Using
        PictureBox2.Invalidate()
        _Previous = e.Location
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub pictureBox2_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseUp
    _Previous = Nothing
End Sub
```

I know there is an mistake somewere, but Im to excited to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this event handler for PictureBox2 you call the handler for PictureBox1:

```
Private Sub pictureBox2_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseDown

    _Previous = e.Location
    pictureBox1_MouseMove(sender, e)
End Sub
```

I'm guessing changing it to:

```
pictureBox2_MouseMove(sender, e)
```

will fix it.

Comment: I changed, there is  now some change cause If I start to draw with picturebox2 then it wont interact with picturebox1. But if I start with picturebox1, then the same error happens, I dont press my mouse key but It wont stop interracting.